# Python: Unexpected ImportError

Tags: python, python-module

I have these modules and packages:

```
main.py/                          
        pkg1/                  
            __init__.py
            maclasse1.py

        pkg2/                  
           __init__.py
           maclasse2.py
```

**main.py:**

```
from pkg1 import maclasse1
from pkg2 import maclasse2
if __name__=="__main__":
   MC1=maclasse1.MaClasse1()
   MC1.ma_classe1()
   MC2=maclasse2.MaClasse2()
   MC2.ma_classe2()
```

**maclasse1.py**

```
from pkg2 import maclasse2
class MaClasse1:
   def ma_classe1(self):
       print "Ma Classe 1"
       c2=maclasse2.MaClasse2()
       c2.ma_classe2()
```

**maclasse2.py**

```
from pkg1 import maclasse1
class MaClasse2:
   def ma_classe2(self):
       print"Ma Classe 2"
       mc1=maclasse1.MaClasse1()
       mc1.ma_classe1()
```

When I run the **main.py** file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg1 import maclasse1
  File "/home/nakkini/Desktop/tester/pkg1/maclasse1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg2 import maclasse2
  File "/home/nakkini/Desktop/tester/pkg2/maclasse2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg1 import maclasse1
ImportError: cannot import name maclasse1
```

How to resolve this problem ?

**EDIT:**

Following Tim's comment, I creat a `tohelp.py` in `pkg3` that imports `maclasse1.py` whereas `maclass2.py` imports `tohelp.py` but I still have the same problem.

Comment: You have circular dependencies

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you calrify, please ?

Comment: File A imports file B, and file B imports file A

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, but why is that a problem ?

Comment: This looks like **import recursion**

Comment: Short story: That's how importing system in Python works. Long story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: a needs b to load .. but b needs a ... so it can't load

Comment: @Bastian but each one of them needs the other, so how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: Because file A need file B to be imported completely so it can load, but file B starts importing file A and for importing file A, file A must import file B first...

Comment: *how to deal with this situation ?* make a module that imports both files, and work from there

Comment: Sounds like both modules should be in the same package, if not both classes in the same module. Either that, or the common code that creates the mutual dependency should be refactored into a 3rd module.

Comment: No.. in tohelp.py include both maclasse1.py and maclasse2.py, and remove the imports in the maclasse files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't intend to change architecture, try this:

**maclasse1.py**

```
class MaClasse1:
    def ma_classe1(self):
        from pkg2 import maclasse2
        print "Ma Classe 1"
        c2=maclasse2.MaClasse2()
        c2.ma_classe2()
```

**maclasse2.py**

```
class MaClasse2:
    def ma_classe2(self):
        from pkg1 import maclasse1
        print"Ma Classe 2"
        mc1=maclasse1.MaClasse1()
        mc1.ma_classe1()
```

Comment: Yuck. Keep imports at module level whenever possible!

Comment: Indeed. However this helps to avoid circular import errors. Still, change to architecture is preferable though.

Comment: your solution is a smart way to avoid the problem. Thank you